# BIDS 2008 R2 Custom Legend Color Size

Tags: reporting-services, report

I'm developing a pie chart report, in legend area, the legend color is in rectangle, can it be set to square?

[image]

Comment: You can define a custom palette color what will change the legend color too. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/dd239355.aspx)

Comment: @alejandrozuleta: thank for your comment, however, I can't change the size of the legend. From my screenshot, I would like to change from rectangle to box.